# How to remember variable after function?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Trying to make a variable for scaling with a function

```
var scaling = 1;

function fash(){
var scaling = scaling*0.95;
trace(scaling);
```

The function fash is repeated regularly and I want the scaling variable to shrink gradually. Now it just outputs 0.95 every time.

Comment: It is repeated by having a timer to start another function. The other function restarts the fash function. 
The closing bracket is there, just missed it when typing it in here.

Comment: Remove "var" inside function.

Answer (score 2):

where is the closing } ? and how is it repeated? however, functions have their own scope, so the var scaling in line 1 ISNT var scaling in line 4... remove the var in line 4.

Answer (score 1):

First change the name of the variable inside the function, the way you are doing you are shadowing the global scaling, so its unacessible from the function. After that turn scaling into a array and at the end of the function push the result into scaling. You will have a whole history of scalings.

Just made a little edit,

```
var scaling = [];

function fash(originalScaling){
  var scalingAux = originalScaling*0.95;
  scaling.push(scalingAux);
}

var someScaling = 10;
fach(someScaling);
console.log(scaling[0]); // 9.5
```